# How to import data from a CSV file in a figure caption using csvsimple?

Tags: captions, csv, csvsimple

I have made a pretty report that gets all the data from CSV files `data.csv` like this :

```
Images,Infos,Bayer,BilineaireA,BilineaireB,TeinteA,TeinteB,ContourA,ContourB,Forme

img1(illusion),Temps (en ms),0,4,5,7,6,6,7,442
img1(illusion),Erreur MSE,152.44,34.44,34.44,24.04,24.04,24.06,25.99,32.90
img1(illusion),Erreur DeltaE,17.70,4.92,4.92,4.58,4.58,4.39,4.30,5.24
img1(illusion),Erreur PSNR (en dB),26.30,32.76,32.76,34.32,34.32,34.32,33.98,32.96

img2(points1),Temps (en ms),0,1,4,3,3,2,3,123
img2(points1),Erreur MSE,6.28,3.83,3.83,3.24,3.28,2.69,2.36,2.56
img2(points1),Erreur DeltaE,0.79,1.09,1.09,0.72,0.72,0.63,0.34,0.60
img2(points1),Erreur PSNR (en dB),40.15,42.30,42.30,43.02,42.97,43.83,44.41,44.05
...
```

I've written many macros like the one below which reads the MSE error for an image `#1` generated using a given algorithm `#2` (be gentle, it's the first time I write my own macro !) :

```
\newcommand{\MSE}[2]{%
\csvreader[ head to column names,%
            before filter=\ifthenelse{ \equal{\Images}{#1} }{%
                          \ifthenelse{ \equal{\Infos}{Erreur MSE} }{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}%
                           }{\csvfilterreject}]% 
          {data.csv}{}{#2}%
}
```

Nevertheless, it seems that I can't use my macros inside captions of figures (and subfigures too). Here is a minimal example that fails :

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Images,Infos,Bayer,BilineaireA,BilineaireB,TeinteA,TeinteB,ContourA,ContourB,Forme

img1(illusion),Temps (en ms),0,4,5,7,6,6,7,442
img1(illusion),Erreur MSE,152.44,34.44,34.44,24.04,24.04,24.06,25.99,32.90
img1(illusion),Erreur DeltaE,17.70,4.92,4.92,4.58,4.58,4.39,4.30,5.24
img1(illusion),Erreur PSNR (en dB),26.30,32.76,32.76,34.32,34.32,34.32,33.98,32.96
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\MSE}[2]{%
\csvreader[ head to column names,%
            before filter=\ifthenelse{ \equal{\Images}{#1} }{%
                          \ifthenelse{ \equal{\Infos}{Erreur MSE} }{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}%
                           }{\csvfilterreject}]% 
          {data.csv}{}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    My Image
    \caption{A caption \MSE{img1(illusion)}{\BilineaireA} }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can read `! TeX capacity exceeded`. If I put my command inside a `minipage` environment, I get the following error :

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: More information is needed: a sample of the CSV file, for instance. However you might try with `\protect\MSE{...}{...}`

Comment: This is just perfect ! It will be my accepted answer if you write your solution below.

Comment: Please, add the info I requested, so that both the question and the answers can be more complete.

Comment: I didn't know the `filecontents` environment, it's very convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An error message such as

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }
```

usually means that a command in the argument of `\caption` needs protection. In this case the command is surely `\MSE`. Thus

```
\caption{A caption \protect\MSE{img1(illusion)}{\BilineaireA}}
```

might solve the problem.

However, in this particular application `\protect` is not sufficient. We need something that contains the value we need, so a different road can be taken. Define a similar `\MSEset` macro, that takes also an optional argument (default value `\MSEresult`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Images,Infos,Bayer,BilineaireA,BilineaireB,TeinteA,TeinteB,ContourA,ContourB,Forme

img1(illusion),Temps (en ms),0,4,5,7,6,6,7,442
img1(illusion),Erreur MSE,152.44,34.44,34.44,24.04,24.04,24.06,25.99,32.90
img1(illusion),Erreur DeltaE,17.70,4.92,4.92,4.58,4.58,4.39,4.30,5.24
img1(illusion),Erreur PSNR (en dB),26.30,32.76,32.76,34.32,34.32,34.32,33.98,32.96
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand{\MSE}[2]{%
\csvreader[ head to column names,%
            before filter=\ifthenelse{ \equal{\Images}{#1} }{%
                          \ifthenelse{ \equal{\Infos}{Erreur MSE} }{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}%
                           }{\csvfilterreject}]% 
          {data.csv}{}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\MSEset}[3][\MSEresult]{%
\csvreader[ head to column names,%
            before filter=\ifthenelse{ \equal{\Images}{#2} }{%
                          \ifthenelse{ \equal{\Infos}{Erreur MSE} }{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}%
                           }{\csvfilterreject}]% 
          {data.csv}{}{\xdef#1{#3}}%
}
\newbox{\remibox}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    My Image
\MSEset{img1(illusion)}{\BilineaireA}
    \caption{A caption \MSEresult}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You set the macro before typing the `\caption` and use `\result` to stand for the value. You can also say

```
\MSEset[\MSEresultA]{img1(illusion)}{\BilineaireA}
```

or any control sequence you want if you need more than one of these numbers. Take care of using control sequence names that are not used elsewhere (a common prefix such as `MSE` should do).

This will print the correct value also in the List of Figures, should you need it.

Comment: Finally I found a solution. I need to add a second `\protect` command like this : `\protect\MSE{img1(illusion)}{\protect\BilineaireA}`

Comment: @RémiG. The second `\protect` might work, but it won't do any good if you want a list of figures. I've added a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you, I've understood ! I think I'll have to buy a LaTeX book if I want to go deeper and automate more things...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving your caption in a `lrbox` and then call from your caption with a `\usebox` command?

Here's some sample code:

```
\newsavebox{\mycaption}
\begin{lrbox}{\mycaption}
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \MSE{img1(illusion)}{\BilineaireA}    
    \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    My Image
    \caption{\usebox{\mycaption}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why the `minipage` and `lrbox`? Wouldn't `\sbox{\mycaption}{\MSE{...}{...}}` work?

Comment: Indeed, the `minipage` environment is useless. I don't get a correct output with the `\sbox` command (letters instead of numbers).

Comment: I didn't have the cvs data at the time.  Something seemed to be fragile and I figured the `minipage` might get around this.